# Parse install path of Google Chrome from registry

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, registry

I am trying to find the install path for Google Chrome from the registry in Powershell. I am able to do so, but I am trying to get only the install path returned, i.e `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.

I am able to see the path from running `GetItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command`, but I need to do further filtering to just return the path and nothing else. I am new to Powershell and I am struggling to find anything in the docs to help with this.

`Current Output:`

```
HIVE: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open

Name                    Property
----                    ----
command                 (default) : "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- 
                        single argument %1
```

`Desired Output:`

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

This is a standard Chrome install on Windows 10.

Comment: `Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command' -Name "(default)"` - [Get-ItemPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do this:

```
$key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command'
$res = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key)."(default)" -replace " *--.*", ""
```

or another method , maybe more intuitive:

```
$res = (Get-Item -Path $key).GetValue("") -replace " *--.*", ""
```

result:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```